# Activemq in disaster recovery site

Tags: activemq-classic, disaster-recovery, activemq-artemis

We use activemq as a critical path in our solution.
We are creating a DR site so we want to implement a master-slave configuration.
We are using KahaDB but as this http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb-master-slave.html is not supported, we can't really use it in a production environment.
Shared disk is a single point of failure so it is not a real DR.
JDBC is slower.
Did anyone implemented such a solution? Which option is the most reliable and not affecting performance?

I read about ActiveMQ Artemis and it seems like it has the master-slave feature I need but I couldn't find how can I migrate my current activemq.xml queues configuration file to Artemis so if anyone has tips about migrating ActiveMQ to ActiveMQ Artemis it will be really helpful as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - there are options to have a DR copy of the ActiveMQ database.

- Let the infrastructure handle it - shared disk does not need to be single point of failure and can be replicated/mirrored on storage level. Depends on your infra tech stack though.
- LevelDB can be replicated among several nodes - hence does not require a shared storage

Anyhow - Artemis is probably the best way forward.

There is no official migration path from AMQ5 to Artemis, but most features in AMQ can be found one way or another in Artemis. Clients should work ootb as well. In the end - it depends on how much custom configuration you're using. Try ask a specific question if you hit any obstacle in migration and you will likely get help sorting that out.